# Is 'Zuhörzimmer' a consultation room?

Tags: meaning, translation

I see the word 'Zuhörzimmer' written on the door when I'm watching interviews featuring doctors. To an English-speaker, this would read as "to listen room," but I'm guessing it refers to the doctor's consultation room, rather than a room where you get a hearing test done or you talk about your problems and they listen (like a therapist's office)?

Here is the video that I'm referring to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1V3Xu5mPVSI
You can see at time 0:01, the door the doctor is standing next to says "Zuhörzimmer" under Sprechzimmer.

I checked on Google, but there is nothing actually defining the specific purpose of the room and I've never visited a doctor's office in Germany in person so I don't know what one looks like. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The consultation room at a doctor's is usually called *Sprechzimmer* ("speaking room"). If - as in the video you linked - a doctor writes *Zuhörzimmer* (instead or in addition of *Sprechzimmer*), which means "listening room" indeed, they want to express that they listen to their patients carefully (implying that they take extra time for this).

In Germany, it is a common lament that doctors don't have (or don't take) enough time to really listen to the needs of their patients. This is also a common critique of suppliers of esoteric and alternative health approaches about the established medical practice.

So, this sign is some sort of a pun based on the opposition to *Sprechzimmer* and referring to that common problem.

Comment: That would make sense, as the patient they are interviewing talks about how he prefers the care he receives there, over the modern style of care where he's made to wait for ages and then the appointment is rushed.

Comment: Googling for "Zuhörzimmer" leads to several people expressing this sentiment.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, was das mit Esoterik zu tun, dass sich ärztliche Praxen rechnen müssen und deshalb höchstwahrscheinlich der eine oder andere Patient mit irgend einer Pille *abgefrühstückt* wird, obwohl *Zühören* die eigentlich angebrachte, nebenwirkungsfreie (leider nicht unbedingt die profitableste) Therapie wäre.

Comment: @Olafant Ich verstehe nicht, wie sich dein Kommentar auf die Antwort bezieht.

Comment: @Olafant Da hast Du Recht, mehr *Zuhören* wäre gut. Die Realität ist aber leider so, dass intensives ärztliches Zuhören nicht nur keine Einnahmen bringen, sondern auch sehr viel Zeit kostet. So traurig das auch ist: Auf einen Termin würdest Du dann noch länger warten als heute schon. Außer Du bist Privatpatient ... Nur zur Klarstellung: Ich bin kein Arzt ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In this video the physician makes a statment regarding common complaints that doctors don't acutally listen to their patients and instead just prescribe some medication that often has nothing to do with what actually ails the patient (often psychological disorders and problems of life). This doctor says that she doesn't just talk to the patient (implied in *Sprechzimmer*, literally "talking room", in the top sign) but listens (*Zuhörzimmer*, "listening room").

[image]

*image from the linked video*

---

*Comment (in German)*

Diese Bedeutung, die ich aus dem Kontext der Verwendung erschließe, ist keine allgemeingültige Bedeutung des Wortes *Zuhörzimmer*. Das Wort ist nicht Teil des allgemeinen Sprachgebrauchs und andere Menschen verwenden das Wort – falls sie es überhaupt verwenden – möglicherweise mit anderer Bedeutung.

*Sprechstunde*, und das davon abgeleitete *Sprechzimmer*, meint eigentlich eine Zeit (bzw. einen Raum), während der jemand *zu sprechen* ist, und ist eine Lehnübersetzung des aus dem Lateinischen übernommenen Fremdworts *Konsultation* "Aufsuchen eines Arztes oder anderen Experten um eine Beratung zu erhalten; Beratung; Zeit in der die Beratung erteilt wird" (cf. engl. *consultation*).

Comment: 'she doesn't just talk to the patient (implied in Sprechzimmer, literally "talking room"' - for the sake of fairness, I think it *should* be pointed out that it's also commonly understood as the room where the *patient* can talk to the doctor. Which, come to think of it, can also turn the joke around, as if the doctor were telling patients to shut up and pay attention to what the doctor is saying.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This idea, that this turns around to the doctor, came to my mind as well. This is a doctor taking a rather self-centrist view, when they thought "Sprechzimmer" was referring to _them_ talking, while it meant that the patients were supposed to talk in the first place.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Die Frage hier ist aber nicht, welche Assoziationen fallen uns alle zu den Begriffen *Sprechzimmer* und *Zuhörzimmer* ein, sondern, was ist damit gemeint. Um das Gemeinte zu erschließen, müssen wir uns mit der Intention des Sprechers (wenn es, wie hier, um Einzelbelege geht) oder der gewöhnlichen Verwendung (bei der Bedeutung von Wörten im Allgemeinen) beschäftigen. Was du hier gerade machst, ist überlegen, was Wörter alles bedeuten *könnten*. Das ist aber nicht nur für die Frage nicht relevant, sondern auch sonst wenig hilfreich. [weiter]

Comment: [weiter] Denn natürlich könnte mit *rot* auch ein *Brot* ohne ***B**utter* gemeint sein oder mit *Zimmermann* ein männliches *Zimmermädchen* usw. Das wird damit aber nicht gemeint, und deshalb sind diese Einfälle nicht nur nicht hilfreich, sondern für Menschen, die die Sprache lernen und ihre Verwendung verstehen wollen, sogar hinderlich. Weshalb ich dich bitten würde, deinen Kommentar zu löschen.

Comment: @fluctuatingpsychosis: Mit "Sprechzimmer" ist aber doch gemeint, dass man dort mit dem Arzt sprechen kann - das erklärst du mittlerweile sogar selber in deiner Antwort. Somit ist mein Kommentar ja exakt passend zur Frage. Zudem bietet mein Kommentar durch den Hinweis auf die mögliche Umkehrung des Witzes *gerade* für Lernende der Sprache eine hilfreiche Erklärung, wie das Wort "Zuhörzimmer" je nach Kontext (falsch?) verstanden werden kann.

Comment: Könntet ihr euch einfach drauf einigen, dass wohl gemeint ist, dass in dem Zimmer *beide* - also Arzt und Patient - sprechen und zuhören sollten?